# In flask,how to query data use a selectfield as condition and display with pagination

Tags: python-2.7, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to query data,use the selectfield as a condition,then show the result in a html and use paginage.
my question is when i display my data，the first can display normally but when i click the next_page，the selectfield is none and the data can not display.
what should I do to keep the selectfield when I click the next_page？

Comment: How about store the selectfield in the url of next page when render the template？

Comment: @stamaimer，I store  the selectfield.data in the url of next page ,it work.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view should accept an integer to allow for the passing of the current datum. Below is an example:

```
@app.route('/view/<int:page>',methods=['GET'])
def view(page=1):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    select = int(request.form.get('select'))
    print(select)
  per_page = 2
  try:
    users = User.query.order_by(User.email.asc()).paginate(select,
                                                           per_page=per_page,
                                                           error_out=False)
  except NameError: 
    users = User.query.order_by(User.email.asc()).paginate(page,
                                                           per_page=per_page,
                                                           error_out=False)
  return render_template('view.html',users=users)
```

The view would look something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>Welcome</head>
  <body>
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('view', page=users.prev_num + 1) }}">
  <div>
    <div>
       <span>Please select</span>
        <select name="select">
          {% for user in users.items %}
            <option value="{{ user.id }}">{{ user.username }}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
  </div>
</form>
{% if users.has_prev %}<a href="{{ url_for('view', page=users.prev_num) }}">&lt;&lt; Newer users</a>{% else %}&lt;&lt; Newer posts{% endif %} | 
{% if users.has_next %}<a href="{{ url_for('view', page=users.next_num) }}">Older users &gt;&gt;</a>{% else %}Older posts &gt;&gt;{% endif %}

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: :thank you. I can use the paginage like you shared,I wang to query data

Comment: my question is when I use paginage and query my data with selectfield as acondition，the first page can display normally but when i click the next_page，the selectfield is none and the data can not display. what should I do to keep the selectfield when I click the next_page？